# The Global class of a managed package(1GP) with a JsonAccess annotation does not display the subscriber organisation

Tags: apex, managed-package, beta-managed-package

The Global class of a managed package(1GP) with a JsonAccess annotation does not display the subscriber organisation.

```
@JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')
global with sharing class PaymentWrapper{

    @JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')
    global class Field{
        global String id;
        global String type;
    }
}
```

I made this global with the JsonAccess annotation because Manage Package and Subscriber can use the same class to wrap data that is coming from a third-party system.

The JsonAccess annotation, however, is not visible in Subscriber Org after packaging, and the subscriber end data is not wrapped in this class.

What is the issue?

Comment: When you say not visible, where is it not visible? In the Setup UI?

Comment: When I'm opening the class in Subscriber org then `@JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always') ` is not visible in that org.

Comment: Subscriber Org Code
`global class MEP_ListWrapper {
global class Field {
    global String id;
    global String type;
    global Field() {

    }
  }
}`

Comment: Does that stop it being used? The global class presentation on the subscriber org Setup UI does not show the code directly after all...

Comment: Actually I'm able to access the class in Subscriber Org but the `@JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')` is not visible. As a result, I am unable to encapsulate data in this class format in Subscriber org.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide what you tried and where you are stuck, including verbatim any error messages.